# Security Unit unlock after certain main mission

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain

One of the requirements to develop D-Dog's Sneaking Suit (stun) is Security Unit level 20. I am currently on Main Mission 20 and I do not have the security unit yet. When is it unlocked?

I have an option to auto assign staff members prioritizing security unit over combat unit, but this doesn't do anything actually, so my guess is it needs to be unlocked first after completing certain main mission. I tried googling, but was unable to find *anything* about security unit at all. It was not even listed on wikis and other pages about MGS V - is it a part of combat unit, perhaps?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There will be an event at mission 21 that will start mission 22 which unlocks the FOB (Forward Operating Base) element of the game.

When this is unlocked, you will get the security team added as this team is the one that defends the base. The security team level is based on the combat skill of the members in the team.

Comment: Although all answers are helpful, you, sir, were the fastest (not considering the edit your answer was still as helpful as the others), so the green tick of gratitude is yours. I upvoted other answers too.

Answer (score 4):

The Security Team becomes available after Mission 22, which introduces the FOB mechanics. It is, in fact, separate from the Combat Team, though it also uses Combat ability as its rank-criteria statistic.

You're almost there!

Answer (score 3):

You're very close - it unlocks after Mission 22. That's all I can say without getting into spoiler territory.